# Is it possible to design a web application using only Python and django?

Tags: python, django

I want to develop a web application using pure python and django. Can I accomplish with out using angularJS or any Javascript? I know to use angular tags in django. But will this be necessary for a perfect running application?

```
{{% verbatim %}}
{{% endverbatim %}}
```

Comment: Just keep experimenting. Find something you want to build and build it. Some problems can only be solved with Javascript. *Most* problems can be solved with Django alone. But you won't have any conception of this until you significantly work toward building something.

Comment: Define "perfect". There is nothing stopping you from creating a fully functional web app if the only programming language you know is Python and a framework (in this case Django).

Comment: I developed an application using Python, Flask, AngularJS and it is "Perfect" running good. But in my new application I just want to use python, django and MySQL, I digged into django docs and I found very less about front-end development using only django.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.  Libraries such as React and Angular are just JavaScript code which runs in the browser but it's main purpose, especially for react, is to be the view which in Django speak, is the template.   Django has a template engine included for you and very powerful sites have been written without React, Angular, Vue etc... using just simple Python Django.

I would say, unless you have a specific need to use one of those libraries than don't use them.   They won't save time or maintenance.   This is definitely anecdote, but from my personal experience, we don't need Angular or React for 90% of the websites out there.  The 10% that do need it... it's a life saver.